# TestFlight users not asking for or saving Camera Permissions

Tags: swift, xcode, permissions, camera, testflight

I have an app with a built-in QR scanner that can be used to scan and present String contents of QR codes. When the app is first run on a device, it should prompt for Camera access (included in info.plist appropriately). This is how it works when I test on my device, as well as when my partner does on his (both internal testers).

Once we released our app to TestFlight, however, users have reported not being asked for Camera Permission on first run, and the QR scanner has all of a sudden been unusable for our TestFlight users.

Since noticing this issue in TestFlight, I have programmatically added a request for camera permissions when the user presses the QR scanner button, following some previous issues posted on Stack Overflow. This update has enabled me to prompt our TestFlight users for permission and take them to Settings to allow access. However, even after allowing camera access to our app in Settings, the app still does not start the camera session for TestFlight users as it does in my and my partner's apps.

```
'''
func promptForCameraAccess() {
    let settingsAppURL = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!
    let alert = UIAlertController(
        title: "Need Camera Access",
        message: "Camera access is required to use the QR scanner.",
        preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .cancel, handler: { (alert) -> Void in
        UIApplication.shared.open(settingsAppURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }))
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func proceedWithCameraAccess() {
    let cameraAuthorizationStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video)
    switch cameraAuthorizationStatus {
        case .notDetermined: requestCameraPermission()
        case .authorized: willPresentQRScanner(true)
        case .restricted, .denied: promptForCameraAccess()
    @unknown default:
        presentCustomAlert(title: "Error", message: "An unknown error occurred. Please try again later.")
    }
}

func requestCameraPermission() {
    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video, completionHandler: { accessGranted in
        guard accessGranted == true else { return }
        self.willPresentQRScanner(true)
    })
}
'''
```

Once the app recognizes permission for camera, it should call the function willPresentQRScanner, and show the QR scanner for the user. This is how it works on my device as well as my partner's device, but not for TestFlight users.

I am trying to understand if there is something simple I am missing when dealing with user permissions in TestFlight. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: in case of `case .restricted, .denied` you cannot ask for camera access. You can only show an error to the user and ask them to resolve it manually going to permissions screen. Also make sure you have proper keys in info.plist. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_ios